# What is bingsandbox.com?

Tags: domains, web-crawlers, bing, referrer, whois

I toyed around a with "Bing Webmaster Tools": https://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster

And then checked `access.log`. 
One `referrer` was `http://www.bingsandbox.com/`

---

Link: http://www.bingsandbox.com/

[`whois`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/whois/) gives following result (web link: http://whois.domaintools.com/bingsandbox.com)

`Domain Name: bingsandbox.com` *[..]*
 
`Tech Organization: Microsoft Corporation` *[..]*
`Tech City: Redmond` *[..]*
`Name Server: ns3.msft.net` *[..]*

---

Information about: https://www.bingsandbox.com/

From: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=www.bingsandbox.com

`Common name: a248.e.akamai.net`
 
`SANs: *.akamaihd.net, *.akamaihd-staging.net, a248.e.akamai.net`
 
`Organization: Akamai Technologies, Inc.`

*(really don't know how to do this from command line)*

Comment: i've taken a look at it looks like an exact copy of bingsandbox.com which is actually hosted in the UK by a company called Akamai Technologies which seem to offer a content delivery network. This would explain the duplication of there content.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about creating or maintaining a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sandbox is the name normally assigned to a test environment (playing area) for a project. Given that http://bing.com is the Microsoft search engine and the whois reveals the domain is a Microsoft property, I assume that's a test version of the search engine.

It's likely it's used to deploy and test new features in a production-like environment without affecting the main search engine. This is useful because, if something goes wrong and the sandbox crashes, this is not likely to affect real users and the real production app.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Simone, with the name `bingsandbox.com` it seems very likely that the site will become a development environment without actually having any effect on their actual search results. Whether this be for the public or whether it be for people like us too test new features that they need testing and feedback, who knows. There doesn't seem to be any answer or news from Bing as to what this domain is for, and at present is just a mirror image of their current site.

What is interesting is that the domain itself has been registered in the UK and is being hosted in the UK, not USA. Also another interesting aspect is that Bing on `bing.com` are currently using their own DNS servers and hosting, however pinging `bingsandbox.com` reveals the following:

```
Pinging a134.1m.akamai.net [92.122.208.51] with 32 bytes of data
```

`a134.1m.akamai.net` is run by a company called Akamai Technologies who are a London based company that seem to specialize in content delivery networks, whether it be just HTML, CSS, JS or whether it be as complex as complete applications / systems. So my guess is as good as anyone's. Until they release a post explaining what it is, then who knows it could be anything.

Comment: Just a side-note: [Akamai Technologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akamai_Technologies) is headquartered in the U.S. (Cambridge, Massachusetts). They were a forerunner in content deliver networks, specifically in video streaming (I used to consult for them in the '90's).

Comment: I did notice that after I posted about the company however I also noted that the ip was linked to there London office, I'm sure I read that but can't remember now.